# How do I make my windows "wavy"?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, settings, window-management

I installed an Ubuntu version about 6 months ago, and in the appearance settings, I could check a box that made the windows "wavy" when you move them.  Like, whenever you moved a window side to side, it made them look like gravity was affecting it.  I forgot what the term was for this, but I can't seem to find a place to do this in the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you asking about "[Wobbly Windows](http://youtu.be/4u71PCEXV3o)"? (YouTube link) And by latest version, you mean Ubuntu 11.10, right?

Comment: Yes...  I don't know how to get to preferences in the new Unity 11.10.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/833/18612

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set wobbly windows up.

## Traditional method

The traditional way to do this is by using the **CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`)**. Install it by searching for it in the Ubuntu Software Center or by entering in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You can then  open it by searching for it in the Unity dash or by running `ccsm` in either the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt or a terminal.

Once in CompizConfig Settings Manager, look for the Wobbly Windows plugin under Effects:

[image: CCSM with Wobbly Windows plugin highlighted]

All you should need to do is click the checkbox next to it to turn the plugin on, and windows should start jiggling around. You may have to restart compiz with a `compiz --replace` in the terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> if it doesn't take effect right away.

Within the plugin itself you should also be able to tweak some related settings to configure it just the way you want it.

> ## WARNING
>
> CompizConfig Settings Manager is [known to break Unity](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/18612) if you mess
>   around with certain settings or options in it, even ones that seem
>   innocent enough. You are taking a risk by following these instructions
>   or any other answers that recommend the use of CCSM.

## Alternative method

If you want to enable wobbly windows but don't want to take the risks involved with using `ccsm`, you can also set this option using Ubuntu Tweak, under **Tweaks > Compiz Settings > Desktop Effects**:

[image: Location of wobbly windows setting in Ubuntu Tweak]

See [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/18612) for installation instructions.

Comment: Hey, this question is a dupe of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67480/how-do-i-get-the-window-jelly-effect), please move your question there if you think it has information that is not contained on the answers.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Instructions for how to do this using `ccsm` are already present on the other question in another answer. At any rate, I saw this question before seeing the other...you're right though, chronologically this one is a dupe of the other.

Comment: Sorry man, thats the way it goes. Gave you another +1, keep on the good work and those flags coming!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see Wobbly plugin in the list of CompizConfig Settings Manager, please follow this:

1. Click this to install  [Synaptic Package Manager [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic)from Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Invoke Synaptic Package Manager and search for `compiz-plugins`, right click on it and select "Mark for Installation", click on Apply.
3. Invoke `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager) from Command Window or Unity Dash, and go to Preferences → Plugin List tab.
4. Select **Wobbly** from the list on left side (Disabled Plugins) and click on > button to move it over to Enabled Plugins list.

You should now be able to see Wobbly under Effects of CCSM's main screen.

You can now click on the check-box and enable the effect.